# Is the Random Variable's Expectation the optimal Solution for the Mean Squared Error?

Tags: optimization, expected-value, mean-square-error

Lets assume we compute the Mean Squared Error between an estimated, but fixed variable $\hat{x}$ and a dataset ${x_1, x_2,...,x_n}$, sampled from a non-gaussian distributed random variable $\mathcal{X}$:

$$
\frac{1}{N} \sum^N_i (\hat{x} - x)^2.
$$

My intuition is, that the variable $\hat{x}$ that minimizes this error is the expectation of the distribution of $\mathcal{X}$, is this correct? And if yes, how to proof it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exact. Suppose your samples have the same law than a random variable $X$.

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$ be any number. Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N (a - x_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N \left[(a - \mathbb{E}[X])^2 + 2(a - \mathbb{E}[X])(\mathbb{E}[X] - x_i) + (\mathbb{E}[X] - x_i)^2\right].
$$
Now, the first term in the sum is just positive. That means that the above is greater or equal than
$$
2(a - \mathbb{E}[X])\sum_{i=1}^N (\mathbb{E}[X] - x_i) + \sum_{i=1}^N (\mathbb{E}[X] - x_i)^2.
$$
The second term is just the means square error for the expectation and the first term is zero, because evaluate the mean of $\mathbb{E}[X] - X$ (multiplied by $N$ to be precise). All in all, we get
$$
\dfrac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (a - x_i)^2 \geq \dfrac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (\mathbb{E}[X] - x_i)^2
$$
with equality if and only if $a = \mathbb{E}[X]$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you elaborate on a few things: **1.** How did you expand the first equation?
**2.** How is the first part of the second term zero? Subtracting every sample from the mean should not be zero, except in the case of a distribution that is symmetric around the mean.
**3.** Otherwise you basically showed that the expectation for $a$ defines a lower bound for the error, hence every other value for $a$ must cause a greater error, right? Is this a known theorem, or you just figured it out now?

Comment: @Chris 1. It's simply the binomial identiy $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$. 2. You are totally right, I misread the question. What you might want to try is that this is true in the limit, because of the law of large numbers. But indeed, it might not be true if you sample a finite number. My solution is the proof that $\mathbb{E}[(X-a)^2]$ is minimized for $a = \mathbb{E}[X]$, i.e. for the variance. My bad. 3. This method is quite a usual way to proceed if you want to show minimality. I don't think that there is a particular theorem for this..?

Comment: 1. Ok, but you expanded $(a-x_i)^2$ to $(a - \mathbb{E}[X] - x + \mathbb{E}[X])^2$ before applying the binomial identity, right? 2. I understand, but in that case the proof would go along the same line still (except for not including sums because we are in the continuous domain)? And then $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X] - X] = \mathbb{E}[X] - \mathbb{E}[X] = 0$?

Comment: 1. Exactly. 2. I don't understand you question... But the second point is it. (If you have a discrete random variable, you can still write it as sums.

Comment: With my second question I just meant (even in the continuous case) the whole proof would still work out with the same steps. And the critical step that didn't work out with samples, would turn into the equation that be comes zero, which I wrote down in my previous comment. Right?

Comment: Yes. I believe so.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help :)